# which of these statements are correct to say?

Tags: grammar

which of these statements are correct to say?

1. Which could lead them losing weight.
2. which could lead to them losing weight.

Answer (score 2):

As is described in the [LongMan](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/lead)
The structure is like this :

> lead [someone] to [something]/[do something]

And after "to" the verb doesn't have "ing"
So it becomes :

> Which could lead them **to** lose weight.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the ELL. Your answer could be improved by adding references. See [how](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).